# Laravel blueprint inet type for postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, blueprint

I needed a migration in my project (laravel) to create some new tables, one of these tables must have a column with `inet` type, so I did this:

```
Schema::create('host_servers', static function (Blueprint $t) {
    //...
    $t->addColumn('inet', 'ip');
    //...
});
```

but when I run `php artisan migrate` it say:

> `BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar::typeInet does not exist.`

Comment: Try using `$t->ipAddress('ip');`, it should create a column of the type inet for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [@Remul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9193055/remul) comment, the answer is [`ipAddress`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_ipAddress) :

```php
$t->ipAddress('column_name');
```